# Why does gain of my INA2332 change with increase in input voltage?

Tags: temperature, gain, instrumentation-amplifier

I'm building an IoT circuit for sensing resistance change using Kelvin's 4 wire.

I have implemented a constant current source that supplies my two sensors connected in series with 50 mA.  The output of each sensor is approximately 15 mV (I introduce common-mode voltage of 1 V by adding a 20ohm resistor in series.)

Now I have connected the two voltage output wires of two sensors to the two differential inputs of INA2332 and set the gain 100 as you can see in my schematics.

[image: Resistance sensor with temperature compensation]

[image]

I'm using a 10k resistor as R1 and 10k + 180k as R2 as suggested for INA2332 here.

[image: INA2332 block diagram]

The INA2332-A has a gain of 1320.3/15.4 = 85.7337 V/V with the value of corresponding Rcomp resistor = 304 mΩ and the gain of INA2332-B is the same as stated 1663.2/15.2 = 109.421 V/V with the value of corresponding Rx resistor = 305 mΩ, was measured at a temperature of 26°C.

At 45°C, the measured values are: INA2332-A has a gain of 1400.6/16.5 = 84.884 V/V and INA2332-B has a gain of 1662.2/16.3 = 101.975 V/V.
It is already demonstrated that the sensor successfully compensates for the temperature.

My idea is to make a portable device that measures the ratio Rx/Rcomp (which should remain the same irrespective of the temperature) and performs some other calculations corresponding to that ratio.

The above values were obtained in my first run of measurements. When I took measurements again the results were disappointing. I couldn't accurately determine the resistance values of Rx and Rcomp from the output values of INA2332. I've attached the result file to take a look at [Results file](https://polimi365-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/10643133_polimi_it/EVo7FT6Ls5VOhJlC_irWY5wBjPKk-WqPQdUWiCOrohp2QA?e=HNLmdy) and I'm also attaching the front of the board layout(the back is just the constant current supply part which works perfectly) just in case I'm missing anything.[image: board layout]

Is it a problem that I put a 20Ω resistor in series to introduce 1 V common-mode voltage because according to the datasheet the Vcm = Vs/2 and my supply to INA2332 is 3.2V from Arduino?

Comment: the schematics is unreadable.

Comment: It is readable to me but I've added another schematic that can give you an idea of what I'm trying to do. Thank you.

Comment: apply known inputs and verify your outputs.  keep it simple. Once you've established you circuit is working as you expect, reinstate your sensor. work logically. if you follow a valid process you will determine the problem. and you'll learn something in the process. Reality is a harsh judge - I can tell you I battle it on a daily basis!

Comment: What is your "R" value?

Comment: value of R is 73 mΩ

Answer (score 0):

> Why does gain of my INA2332 change with increase in input voltage?

Even if the input common mode voltage was the only thing changing, the total gain is composed of differential gain and common mode gain (and what you measure is the combination of both). You may try to estimate it by shorting both the differential inputs and varying your current source or the "common mode resistor".

If not only the two small resistors you are measuring are subjected to the temperature change, but the whole circuit, you can add uncertainty due to drift of the current source, the INAs and the gain resistors, for example.

> Is it a problem that I put a 20Ω resistor in series to introduce 1 V common-mode voltage because according to the datasheet the Vcm = Vs/2 and my supply to INA2332 is 3.2V from Arduino?

You must do this to comply with the [specified](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbos216b/sbos216b.pdf) input range:

[image]

But using the REF pins would also be possible.

Comment: Input common-mode voltage is not the one that is changing. I apologise for not being clear, the input differential voltage is changing(increasing) as the resistance of both the sensors increase with the temperature. Only the sensors are in the climatic chamber, the device is outside. I think I'm already satisfying the condition of the input range as my common-mode voltage is more than 1 V (Rcm = 20Ω) and less then 1.1V max. I've kept my Ref pin grounded. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) As you said that the increase in common-mode voltage is affecting my gain then how can I compensate it in my algorithm if the only information my device on field will have is the output voltage of both the amplifiers? As I'm not well versed in amplifiers please give me a detailed explaination/link(where to learn this) with example if possible. Thank you.